# How do I call the onItemClick method from inside another class?

Tags: java, android, methods, onitemclicklistener, android-adapterview

[Background info: I'm a newbie learning to make a "to do list" app in Android Studio. 
Basically I have a dialog box pop-up when the user clicks on any item in the To Do list, which gives the user a choice of two buttons to 'Delete or Cancel' for any specific item that they click. Then I want that delete button to carry out the code in this method.]

I'm trying to call this onItemClick method (which I made in the MainActivity) from inside a dialog fragment class I created. I don't know what these parameter values are (it seems they are automatically generated) but Android Studio is asking me to pass the four parameters in when I want to call that onItemClick method for the Delete button. This is the method I'm trying to call:

'''

```
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    items.remove(position);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    FileHelper.writeData(items, this); }
```

'''

I defined this method in the MainActivity because all the stuff inside it was created and defined in that activity already (adapterview, items). FileHelper is another class I made.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're using the list. You can check more info for each of the arguments in [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.OnItemClickListener#onItemClick(android.widget.AdapterView%3C?%3E,%20android.view.View,%20int,%20long)) (see the bottom of the page).

- If this is a click listener for your list, where `AdapterView<?> parent` is the parent view of the object that you've clicked - if using `ListView`, this object would be that `ListView`.
- `View view` is the actual view that you've clicked. E.g. if you have a list of `TextView`s and you click on one of them, here you'll get that text view.
- `int position` is the position of the clicked item in your list (0 being the first item).
- `long id` is the id of the clicked item, you usually control that in the adapter.

So if you want to retrieve the clicked element for example, you can use `getItemAtPosition(position)` on your list view to fetch the actual item object.